# Resultset can not be traversed

Tags: java, resultset

I want to use `while(rs.next())` to traverse the `UserInfo` table. There are seven records in `UserInfo` table, but I only got the first record. After I had joined the codes of `rs.getRow();`, I got the result what I want.

```
try{
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    String queryStr="SELECT * FROM UserInfo";
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(queryStr);

    while(rs.next())
    {
        String strName="Name is "+rs.getString(3)+";";
        String intAge="Age is "+rs.getInt(5)+";";
        String strCompany="Company is "+rs.getString(4)+".<br>";
        //int rowNum=rs.getRow();
        out.println(strName+intAge+strCompany);
    }

    out.println("Succeed in visiting UserInfo table.");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        out.println("Failed to query.");
    }
```

I don't want to use `rs.getRow();`. How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't using something like `rs.next()` in the debugger? Your code should be fine.

Comment: The code as you have given looks fine, should work the way you expect, unless it is database level problem, but it does not look that way

Comment: what is the problem? This code should work without any issues and get what you want

Comment: Thanks.I want to output the whole table in the brower.But now I only get the first recorder.

Comment: The database is Access 2007.

Comment: I didn't use the code in the debugger.

Comment: @Chris If you are using `String` to hold a record, then you wouldn't be able to display all 7 records. Ideally you should be using a collection object to hold all the records.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does appear to be fine except the String part.If you are using String to hold a record, then you wouldn't be able to display all 7 records.

Thus try using collection object like ArrayList. And of course you should close connections in finally block.

```
try{
  Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
  String queryStr="SELECT * FROM UserInfo";
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(queryStr);
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  

  while(rs.next()){

    list.add(rs.getString(3));

  }

 System.out.println("rows "+list.size());
 }catch(SQLException e){
    out.println("exception "+e.getMessage());
 }
 finally{
 rs.close();
 stmt.close();
 conn.close();
 }
```

This is good example of how you should be retrieving values from database using collection object.
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jdbc/how-to-retrieve-all-rows-from-mysql-table-using-jdbc/

Comment: Many thanks for your help.These tutorials are very useful for me.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.next` only tells you if there is a next record.

When you run

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(queryStr);
```

This already places the data from the first record into variable `rs`.

In order to advance to the next record you need to run `rs.getRow` but only if there is a

next record (check with rs.next).

Comment: But I ever saw some samples,through using "rs.next()",table can be traversed.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.next()` Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row;

Comment: Thank you.In order to solve my problem,what should I do?